# Malformed URL exception : no protocol

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

http://13.232.62.239/muallim/public/profilePicture/phpyOk6UN.

I am trying to convert this URL to a bitmap image it gives me an error as MalformedUrlException.

This is my following code :

```
    fun getBitmapFromURL(src: String): BitmapDrawable? {
    val connection = URL(src).openConnection()
    connection.connect();
    val input = connection.getInputStream()

    val x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), x)
}
```

where src: String is the URL that I am sending into this method to convert this image link into the bitmap.

PS: If we click the above URL and add a dot(.) the link will show the image.
So my question is: Is it because of the dot (the special character at the end of which is giving the Exception or is it something else)
Can anyone please help me with this. ?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. when i click on link

Comment: I have updated my question please add a dot at the end of the url